# NumberFormatter currency type up to 2 decimal spaces

Tags: swift, number-formatting

I want to covert a String to currency and keep 2 decimal spaces:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh_CN")
formatter.number(from: "¥12")        // Output 12 correct.
formatter.number(from: "¥1213.1263") // Output 1213.1263
formatter.string(from: 1213.1263)    // Output "￥1,213.13"
```

You can see the output in comments. Why not the `formatter.number(from: "¥1213.1263")` output `1213.13`? I have set the max fraction digits is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The `maximumFractionDigits` and all similar properties are only used for formatting the number as a string. They are not used for rounding numbers when using  `NumberFormatter.number(from: String)`.

Comment: But the documentation says: The maximum number of digits after the decimal separator allowed as _input_ and _output_ by the receiver. This means that it should return nil for ¥1213.1263 since no more than 2 fraction digits is allowed in the input. How do you explained this?

Comment: The documentation (as in quite a few other cases) is not 100% accurate. It doesn't state which *input* and/or *output* formats it refers to. You can check for yourself, this is how `NumberFormatter` works and have been working for a long time.